# Initializing ImageView position within layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-view

I have a `RelativeLayout` with a custom ImageView named `ZoomieView` that allows me to pinch-to-zoom on an image. I want to allow the image to grow the entire size of my screen so I set the width and height of `ZoomieView` to `match_parent`. Now I want to also add a header and footer to the RelativeLayout such that the `ZoomieView` sits in between the header and footer like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBgBlackTintDarkest"
    android:id="@+id/full_displayer_master_container"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- Submission header -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/big_display_title_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Image zoom view-->
    <com.sometimestwo.moxie.ZoomieView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/full_displayer_image_zoomie_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <!-- footer -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/full_display_snack_bar_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/snack_bar_selector"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

If I have a small image, this works fine as the image is small enough that it does not cover up the header/footer but when I try loading a large image, the header and footer are covered up since my height/width are match_parent.

I need the height/width to remain match_parent but I also do not want the header/footer to be covered when the view is loaded (it's fine if the header/footer is covered later when the user zooms in on the picture, though).

Is there a way I can resize my image such that `ZoomieView` is centered between my header and footer when the view loads but allows the `ZoomieView` to cover up the header/footer when I zoom in to the image?

Adding `android:layout_below="header"` `android:layout_above="footer"` to my `ZoomieView` would not work because it would not allow the `ZoomieView` to grow the entire screen size when zooming in.

This is what I have now (bad):

[image]

This is how I want the views to be loaded(better):
[image]

Comment: Why you didn't use Linear Layout instead of Relative Layout. It will be easy in this case.

Comment: I believe I did try using LinearLayout. Care to explain what you mean?

Comment: Do you know the size of the header/footer ahead of time? Or is it dynamic at runtime?

Comment: It's dynamic at run time

Answer (score 0):

Change the Layout and use android:layout_weight="0" property

Try This hope it will work...!

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorBgBlackTintDarkest"
android:id="@+id/full_displayer_master_container"
android:orientation="vertical">

<!-- Submission header -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/big_display_title_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>

    <!-- Image zoom view-->
<com.sometimestwo.moxie.ZoomieView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/full_displayer_image_zoomie_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

<!-- footer -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/full_display_snack_bar_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/snack_bar_selector"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...it might help you.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorBgBlackTintDarkest"
android:id="@+id/full_displayer_master_container"
android:orientation="vertical">

<!-- Submission header -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/big_display_title_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>

    <!-- Image zoom view-->
<com.sometimestwo.moxie.ZoomieView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/full_displayer_image_zoomie_view"
    android:layout_above="@+id/full_display_snack_bar_container" //add this line
    android:layout_below="@+id/big_display_title_container" //add this line
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

<!-- footer -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/full_display_snack_bar_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/snack_bar_selector"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
</LinearLayout>
```